# cvs commit and add files in single command

Tags: linux, version-control, cvs

I am using CVS and I want to checkin/submit/commit multiple files. Also there are new files and I want to add those also for the same bug fix.

How can we achieve this in single command so that there will be only one comment/commit-message while committing.

Comment: Don't use CVS in 2013. It is obsolete. Learn about `git` or at least `svn` (and you can convert a CVS repository to them).

Comment: @Basile - I am not using because I want to, but I have to :)

Comment: You could use `git` and push your changes to CVS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you cvs add a file, it only *schedules the file for addition*, it does not add the file to the repository or modify the repository in any way.  When you are ready to commit your new and modified files, you can then do so with a single commit command which will then commit both the added files and the modified files to the repository with only the single comment for the commit.

Comment: Yes. I found it after posting question.